# x86 assembly: ADD/SUB/INC/DEC without overflow and branching

Tags: assembly, integer-overflow

In x86 ASM, is it possible to disallow overflowing when adding or subtracting without branching? So for example, when subtracting 0x02 from 0x01 it would set 0x00 rather than 0xFF.

I expect this may be impossible, so I'm also interested in an answer to a more restricted form of this question where only 0x01 is added/subtracted. I had an idea that goes like this (OF being the overflow flag):

```
dec eax
add eax,OF
```

I don't know about other architectures, but for i386 I couldn't find opcodes for this since apparently flags can't be interpreted as integers and used in arithmetic operations. I found a solution that does work, but only for the lowest byte when the higher byte is unused:

```
dec ax
sub al,ah
xor ah,ah
```

Is there a better way to do this, maybe one that's also applicable to the more general cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `cmov` (*conditional MOV*) family of instructions on newer processors to avoid branching in many cases, including the example you describe. These instructions behave like a regular `mov` if the flag values are set appropriately, or otherwise do nothing.

See http://www.jaist.ac.jp/iscenter-new/mpc/altix/altixdata/opt/intel/vtune/doc/users_guide/mergedProjects/analyzer_ec/mergedProjects/reference_olh/mergedProjects/instructions/instruct32_hh/vc35.htm

However:

> I had an idea that goes like this (OF being the overflow flag)

It's not the overflow flag you want; that indicates that the value overflowed the bounds representable using 2's complement (so for a 16-bit word value, if it became less than -32768 or greater than 32767). You appear to be using unsigned numbers (and want clamping to 0), so what you want is the *carry* flag.

You can use `CMOVC` to load a new value if there was a carry (if the result wrapped from 0 to 0xFF), for instance.

```
sub ax, 1
xor bx, bx
cmovc ax, bx
```

This works when subtracting any value. However, as it turns out, there is a simpler way if you just want a decrement. You can subtract 1, and then add 0 + carry using an instruction which does exactly that:

```
sub ax, 1
adc ax, 0
```

Note that you can't use the `dec` instruction as a substitute for `sub` because `dec` does not affect the carry flag.

For going the other way (addition), you use `sbb` in place of `adc` (and of course `add` in place of `sub`). For the general case, you can do something like:

```
add ax, 1
mov bx, 0FFFFh
cmovc ax, bx
```

Comment: I didn't think the general case could be solved with just three instructions. Great answer, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In the case of incrementing by 1 (using `add #1`, not `inc`) you can just `sbc #0` afterwards to implement saturation. Similarly for decrementing by 1: use `sub #1` followed by `adc #0`.

Alternatively consider using SSE, which supports saturating integer arithmetic operations in a single instruction.

Comment: _"In the case of incrementing by 1..."_ As long as that increment isn't done using `INC`, since `INC` doesn't affect the carry flag.